# Prove that $\sin2C < \sin 2B$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

[https://i.loli.net/2019/11/09/D46dsT523elbCtO.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wg3F.jpg)

In the above image given that $BD=DC$.
Also, $\angle BAD$ $+$ $\angle$ $C$ $>$ $\frac{\pi}{2}$
Prove that - 
$$\sin 2 C < \sin 2B$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @newuser1234 I solved your problem for acute-angled triangle. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Using trigonometry we get
$$\sin(\gamma)\cos(\gamma)<\sin(\beta)\cos(\beta)$$ or $$\frac{\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\beta)}<\frac{\cos(\beta)}{\cos(\gamma)}$$
by the theorem of sines and the theorem of cosines we get
$$\frac{c^2}{b^2}<\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2-c^2}$$ or
$$0<(c^2-b^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)$$
Can you finish?
We can only multiply by $a^2+b^2-c^2$ if $$a^2+b^2>c^2$$ In the other case we have to consider $$c^2(a^2+b^2-c^2)>b^2(a^2+c^2-b^2)$$

Comment: I got what you have written till here. But I still have a difficulty solving the problem. Please post the complete solution ...

Comment: I request you to please post the complete solution ...

Comment: The product of these factors must be positve, and the other two cases doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry, but I'm not getting the idea. I request you to  please post the complete solution ...